# Compile and uncompilable function bug?

Tags: bugs, compile

I think I found a bug, but I still have MMA version 11.0.1 installed. Can somebody please check if this persists in the latest version?

When I compile this function:

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Module[{good},
    good = True;
    If[DuplicateFreeQ[{}] && n == 15, good = False];
    good
  ]
];
```

The result changes once the condition is met:

```
cf[14]
cf[15]
cf[14]
(* True *)
(* False *)
(* False *)
```

Here it is immaterial what list is given to `DuplicateFreeQ`.

### Addendum 1

As @Jason B. and @Michael E2 pointed out, the important thing is that `DuplicateFreeQ` cannot be compiled. Thus, a more general example is

```
fun := True; (* use := so fun cannot be compiled *)
With[{cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{xyz},
     xyz = True;
     If[fun && n == 15, xyz = False];
     xyz
     ]
    ]},
   {cf[14], cf[15], cf[14]}
 ]
 (* {True, False, False} *)
```

Now, @Michael E2 wrote that it seems as if

> there is a runtime environment in the WVM connected to cf, in which the assignment `good = False` leaks out in some form and is stored across calls to cf.

Here is some evidence for that, I think:

1. Quit the kernel.
2. `` ?Global`xyz* `` gives a warning that there is no `xyz` defined.
3. Evaluate

`With[{cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{xyz}, xyz = True; If[n == 15, xyz = False]; xyz]]}, {cf[14], cf[15], cf[14]}] (* {True, False, True} *)`

as it should be.

4. `` ?Global`xyz* `` shows that a `` Global`xyz `` has been defined.
5. Evaluate the code at the beginning of Addendum 1, giving the wrong result `{True, False, False}`, and you find that `` Global`xyz `` as well as `` Global`xyz$ `` are defined, where `` Global`xyz$ `` has the attribute `Temporary`.

Comment: Please don't use the bugs tag before the behavior has been confirmed as a bug by other users as well.

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior in _v9.0.1_

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior in MMA 11.1.1, and indeed it is strange, but I wonder if you are aware that `DuplicateFreeQ` is not compilable, so it causes a call to the main evaluator within your compiled function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `DuplicateFreeQ` - you could use `StringQ[""]` instead.  I can even get the same result with `cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{good}, good = True; If[And[Evaluate[True], n == 15], good = False]; good]];`

Comment: I think the symbol `xyz` is created in evaluating `Compile` and the `xyz$` is created in the `MainEvaluate` call when you run `cf[14]` (or `cf` on anything).  The actual variable used in `cf[14]` has the form `xyz$nnn`, where `nnn` is a serial number, different on each call to `cf` -- these are `Remove`-d but show up in a `Trace`. I think they are probably not the source of the leak, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: It seems that  we have a consensus that this is a bug, so I've added bugs tag. In versions 8.0 and 9.0 I get run-time type error and function switches to uncompiled evaluation. In versions 10.0 -10.3 and 11.0 I can reproduce described (buggy) behavior, interestingly version 10.4.1 gives correct `{True, False, True}` result, I'm not sure how to describe this in standard bugs header. Also behavior is correct for `CompilationTarget -> "C"`, so it indeed seems to be related to *WVM*.

Comment: Can somebody with access to multiple versions please add the customary header?

Answer (score 14):

If you declare the type of `DuplicateFreeQ`, it works consistently (in V11.1.1).

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{good},
    good = True;
    If[DuplicateFreeQ[{}] && n == 15, good = False];
    good],
    {{DuplicateFreeQ[_], True | False}}
   ];
```

One really ought to declare the type of `DuplicateFreeQ`, but it's as yet unclear to me why omitting the declaration does not lead to an error or warning and exhibits the strange behavior in the OP.

---

*Update:*
Without the declaration, `Compile` does not know what to do with the return value of `DuplicateFreeQ[]`, so it has to send off the whole `If[DuplicateFreeQ[{}] && n == 15, good = False]` to `MainEvaluate[]`; but since the value of `good` might be changed, it has to evaluate `good` in `MainEvaluate[]`, too.  The compiled code for this is

```
{46, Function[{n}, If[DuplicateFreeQ[{}] && n == 15, good = False]],
  {good, 1, 0, 0, Module}, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 17}
```

This translates, according to `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint ``, to

```
V17B0 = MainEvaluate[
  Function[{n, goodCompile$1},
   Block[{good = goodCompile$1},
    {If[DuplicateFreeQ[{}] && n == 15, good = False], good}
    ]
   ][ I0, B0]
  ]
```

Note it appears to use `Block` to localize `good`.  At face value this couldn't be good, since it changes the value of a global variable before calling code in the global context. In fact, it does not use `Block` in the way the code suggests, because the value of `` Global`good `` is not affected.  This can be checked in at least of couple of ways, one of which is via an internal `Trace`.  The first time `cf[14]` is called, it looks like this:

```
Trace[cf[14], TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image]

Note `Module` is used, not `Block`, and contains the initialization expression `good$ = True`.  After `c[15]` is called, the same trace of `c[14]` has the initialization `good$ = False`.

Note that recompiling `cf` resets the behavior, so that `cf[14]` will return `True` until `cf[15]` is called.  So does `cf = CompiledFunction @@ cf`.

It does raise in my mind whether there is a runtime environment in the WVM connected to `cf`, in which the assignment `good = False` leaks out in some form and is stored across calls to `cf`.  That's what appears to be happening. This view inclines me to think it's a bug.